# What is inline-view that can be used with LATERAL in Snowflake (not subquery, not table function)?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The [Snowflake documentation for Lateral Join](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/constructs/join-lateral.html) mention that in

```
SELECT ... FROM <left_hand_table_expression>, LATERAL ( <in_line_view> )
```

The `in_line_view` could be:

1. An in-line view (a view defined within the statement, and valid only for the duration of the statement
2. A subquery `select * from d, lateral (select * from e where e.id = d.id)`
3. A table function (either a built-in function such as FLATTEN or a user-defined table function(UDFT)) `select * from e, lateral flatten(input => e.x)`

I **already have used subqueries and table functions** in the `LATERAL(...)` but I wonder what is the the other kind of `<in_line_view>` (and how it is different from a subquery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One significant type of inline view is the Common Table Expression, or CTE.

```
WITH my_in_line_view AS (SELECT ...)
SELECT * FROM my_in_line_view
```

One major point in having all these different way of expressing similar queries is code clarity.

The SQL optimizer may treat all versions as similar, but when reading your code, it may be much simpler to understand if you use well thought out CTEs.  Or maybe not, it can add to the confusion.

Just like natural language, you have many ways of saying the same thing, but some ways are more easily understood.

Comment: Yes, indeed , support answered with the following example `with ILV as (select * from t2) select * from t1, lateral (select * from ILV where t1.id = ilv.id) as reslt;` which I found confusing because to me the LATERAL part is using a subquery which happens to reference a CTE, I thought that you could do `with ILV as (select * from t2) select * from t1, lateral (ILV) as reslt;` but that gives a `SQL execution internal error: Processing aborted due to error 300002:4143448929; incident 5366880.`

Answer (score 1):

Their language here is a little confusing for sure. Really just remove the `1.` bullet from that list and it will make more sense. From what I can tell, the only difference between an "inline view" and a "subquery" is that an inline view is a subquery that is in a specific part of the larger query. In this case, in the `lateral` clause. They even specify in of their examples at the bottom of that page that the FLATTEN is an inline view.

> This example shows how a lateral join can use the in-line view returned by FLATTEN:
>
> ```
> select * from table1, lateral flatten(...);
> ```

To hopefully clarify further, a subquery in the `FROM` clause, for example, has to be run just once and then joined, selected, etc, and so it is treated by the optimizer in a similar way to a view. When you do this it can be referred to as an inline view. However a subquery within a `SELECT` clause has to be run for each record and so isn't treated by the execution plan in the same way.

A rule of thumb is if the query parser forces you to give a subquery an alias, it is probably an "inline view".